# Why does one action produce two jobs?

Tags: performance, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I use Spark 2.1.0.

Why does the following one action produce 2 identical jobs (same DAG in each one)? Shouldn't it produce just 1? Here you have the code:

```
val path = "/usr/lib/spark/examples/src/main/resources/people.txt"
val peopleDF = spark.
  sparkContext.
  textFile(path, 4).
  map(_.split(",")).
  map(attr => Person(attr(0), attr(1).trim.toInt)).
  toDF
peopleDF.show()
```

I see that in the graphic interface when checking what is going on? I suppose it has something to do with all Data Frame transformation.

Comment: What's the Spark version? Can you attach a screenshot of the SQL query and from Jobs?

Comment: Using Spark 2.1.0. Where could I find the "SQL query and from Jobs"? In the GUI just see Jobs, Stages and Tasks. By the way using the history-server.

Comment: History Server should give you a post-execution web UI of your Spark applications so...select a Spark application and you should see SQL tab next to Jobs and Stages. It's enabled by default. What's the cluster manager? YARN?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although in general, a single SQL query may lead to more than one Spark job in this particular case **Spark 2.3.0-SNAPSHOT** gives only one (contrary to what you see).

[image]

The Job 12 is also pretty nice, i.e. just a single-stage no-shuffle Spark job.

[image]

The reason to see more than one Spark job per Spark SQL's structured query (using SQL or Dataset API) is that Spark SQL offers a high level API atop RDDs and uses RDDs and actions freely to make your life as a Spark developer and a Spark performance tuning expert easier. In most cases (esp. when you wanted to build abstractions), you'd have to fire up the Spark jobs yourself to achieve the comparable performance.

Comment: This stage is identical to the one I see but in my standalone Spark cluster I see 2 Jobs. But you already explained why. Jacek, in my case it will take yet long time to go before I become expert. Thanks a lot.